# .net web service issue: Request format is invalid: text/xml

Tags: .net, xml, web-services

I'm writing a simple web service DEMO using .net framework, and I'm testing the web service with a tool named "soapUI". I'm trying to send the request message by HTTP HOST with XML data but I have an issue.

1. Protype of my web method:

```
[WebMethod]
[WebInvoke(ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Xml, RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Xml, BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.WrappedRequest)]
public XmlDocument loginrequest(string XmlString)
{
    XmlDocument Xdoc = new XmlDocument();
    // parse request XML data, and return response XML document
    // ......
    return Xdoc;
}
```

2. Here is my Web.config file:

```
<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <compilation targetFramework="4.5" debug="true"/>
        <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" requestValidationMode="2.0"/>
        <pages validateRequest="false"/>
        <webServices>
            <protocols>
               <add name="HttpGet"/>
               <add name="HttpPost"/>
            </protocols>
        </webServices>    
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```

3. Everything is working just fine if I send HTTP POST Data as following (HTTP Header is omitted here to avoid redundancy, while the ContentType is `application/x-www-form-urlencoded)`:

```
XmlString=%3C%3Fxml%20version%3D%221.0%22%20encoding%3D%22utf-8%22%3F%3E%3CLoginRequest%3E%3CUser%3E%3CUserName%3ETestUser%3C%2FUserName%3E%3CPassword%3E123456%3C%2FPassword%3E%3C%2FUser%3E%3CSeqNum%3E%3C%2FSeqNum%3E%3C%2FLoginRequest%3E
```

4. I got an error message if I send HTTP POST Data as following (This format is exactly what I want, with Content-Type in HTTP header being `text/xml` or `application/xml`):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LoginRequest>
        <User>
            <UserName>TestUser</UserName>
            <Password>123456</Password>
        </User>
        <SeqNum>
        </SeqNum>
    </LoginRequest>
```

Here is the full error message:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: Request format is invalid: application/xml.
   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.HttpServerProtocol.ReadParameters()
   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.WebServiceHandler.CoreProcessRequest()
```

Summary: since the soapUI seems like to be a widely used test tool, it should be fine. What I want to know is that, do I need to change anything in my web service code or `Web.config` to support XML formatted HTTP POST data?

Comment: Seems that something is wrong when I posted the question:

Comment: 2. Web.Config: 
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <compilation targetFramework="4.5" debug="true"/>
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" requestValidationMode="2.0"/>
    <pages validateRequest="false"/>
    <webServices>
      <protocols>
        <add name="HttpGet"/>
        <add name="HttpPost"/>
      </protocols>
    </webServices>    
  </system.web>
</configuration>

Comment: 4. HTTP POST Data with XML format:
POST http://localhost:57496/patt.asmx/loginrequest HTTP/1.1
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate
Content-Type: application/xml
Content-Length: 153
Host: localhost:57496
Connection: Keep-Alive
User-Agent: Apache-HttpClient/4.1.1 (java 1.5)

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><LoginRequest><User><UserName>TestUser</UserName><Password>123456</Password></User><SeqNum></SeqNum></LoginRequest>

Answer (score 0):

Actually what I was trying to do, is send a XML string as the entity-body of a HTTP POST request, instead of a query string. I'm still not sure why I got

> Invalid request format

But finally I've solved the issue by reading the request entity-body through `HttpContext.Current.Request.InputStream`.

Answer (score -2):

please see the following guide:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t745kdsh(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: Link-only answer sould be avoided. Add some more text and explanations.